# GeoJSON from react-leaflet doesn't render the layer over the map

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, geojson, react

I have a GeoServer running on my `localhost` also I have a react app which consumes a WFS service to get a GeoJSON data to render as a layer over the map.

These are my dependencies on my `package.json`

```
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"leaflet": "^1.5.1",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-leaflet": "^2.4.0",
"react-scripts": "3.0.1"
```

And this is my `HomePage.js` in my react app

```
// @packages
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import {
    GeoJSON,
    Map,
    TileLayer
} from 'react-leaflet';

// @constants
const GEOSERVER = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs';

const REQUEST_PARAMS = {
    outputFormat: 'application/json',
    maxFeatures: 250,
    request: 'GetFeature',
    service: 'WFS',
    typeName: 'gaia:mining_titles',
    version: '1.0.0'
};

class HomePage extends PureComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.map = null;
        this.state = {
            center: [6.217679, -75.570648],
            data: null,
            zoom: 8
        };
        this.handleOnMapMounted = this.handleOnMapMounted.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(GEOSERVER, { params: REQUEST_PARAMS })
            .then(({ data }) => this.setState({ data }))
            .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
    }

    handleOnMapMounted(evt) {
        this.map = evt ? evt.leafletElement : null;
    }

    render() {
        const {
            center,
            data,
            zoom
        } = this.state;

        return(
            <Map
                center={center}
                id="home-page-map"
                ref={this.handleOnMapMounted}
                zoom={zoom}
            >
                <TileLayer
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                />
                <GeoJSON data={data} />
            </Map>
        )
    }
}

export default HomePage;
```

When the `componentDidMount` is called the data is set on the state but doesn't render anything and doesn't show errors it just nothing happens.

I already enabled the CORS configuration on my web.xml from my GeoServer

**EDIT:**

This is the response from the GeoServer

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"mining_titles.4133","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[689969.6239,566781.7359],[689969.6246,566381.7341],[690169.6234,566381.7345],[690169.6237,566231.7353],[689873.623,566283.7334],[689757.6244,566421.7352],[689757.6241,566621.734],[689835.6237,566781.7357],[689969.6239,566781.7359]]]]},"geometry_name":"geom","properties":{"id":4133,"objectid":1,"oid_":9918,"id_1":4133,"codigo_exp":"HCS-152","codigo_rmn":"HCS-152","codigo_ant":"HCS-152","fecha_cont":"2006-06-29Z","fecha_insc":"2007-05-17Z","grupo_trab":"PAR PASTO","estado_exp":"TITULO VIGENTE-EN EJECUCION","modalidade":"CONTRATO DE CONCESION (L 685)","minerales":"MATERIALES DE CONSTRUCCION","titulares":"(69021277) CLAUDIA CECILIA BETANCOURT YEPES\\ (12972275) GERMAN NAZARENO BETANCOURT PANTOJA","municipios":"ORITO-PUTUMAYO","fecha_term":"2037-05-16Z","shape_leng":1742.81141444,"shape_area":118628.3028,"grupo":null}}],"totalFeatures":8861,"numberMatched":8861,"numberReturned":1,"timeStamp":"2019-07-16T16:39:34.595Z","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3116"}}}
```

Comment: what is returned from GeoServer?

Comment: @IanTurton I just edited my question with the response from the GeoServer only with 1 feature

Comment: Is your map in web mercator?

Comment: No, I have the project on my localhost

Comment: unless your map is in EPSG::3116 you need to reproject the JSON data

Comment: @IanTurton well my layer called gaia:mining_titles is actually in EPSG:3116 on my geoserver, so how do I transform the response in the REQUEST_PARAMS object?